# How to handle GoogleApiClient instance upon Activity reconnection in Chromecast App?

Tags: android, chromecast

I'm writing a simple app to send public photos from Dropbox public folder to Chromecast.

Instead of CastCompanion library I decided to write my own stuff to understand better the API.

According to Google Guidelines:

> if the sender application becomes disconnected from the media route, such as when the user or the operating system kills the application without the user first disconnecting from the Cast device, then the application must restore the session with the receiver when the sender application starts again.

It seems to me that the same solution should apply to Activity recreation upon orientation change since it recreates the Activity from scratch.

My first question: Is my assumption correct? Both scenarios, orientation change and system kill, may use the same solution?

Given this assumption I wrote some code to restore session upon Activity restoration.

I'm considering the orientation change scenario, when Activity is recreated from scratch and I am supposed to restore route Id, Session Id and try to reconnect (I'm storing and retrieving both values from shared preferences).

I've been testing with and it's working fine.

That's what I do (based on Google Sender Guidelines code):

After discovering the ongoing Route Id and find the cast device I call this method:

```
private void connectToDevice(CastDevice castDevice) {
    Log.d(TAG, "connecting to " + castDevice);

    Cast.CastOptions.Builder apiOptionsBuilder = Cast.CastOptions
            .builder(castDevice, new CastListener());

    Log.d(TAG, "apiClient is null ? " + (apiClient == null));

    apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Cast.API, apiOptionsBuilder.build())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

    Log.d(TAG, "apiClient connected? " + apiClient.isConnected());
    Log.d(TAG, "apiClient connecting? " + apiClient.isConnecting());

    apiClient.connect();
}

private class CastListener extends Cast.Listener {
    @Override
    public void onApplicationStatusChanged() {
        if (apiClient != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "callback => " + this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onVolumeChanged() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationDisconnected(int errorCode) {
        teardown();
    }
}
```

After this method I call `Cast.CastApi.joinApplication` if I recognize a reconnection.

But once reconnected to Chromecast the log of `onApplicationStatusChanged` prints one different instance for every phone's rotation. E.g: if I rotate phone 3 times the log prints 3 times with 3 different pointer addresses. That makes me believe it is internally holding all callbacks instances.

How am I supposed to handle this situation since the Activity is being recreated and I need to create another instance of GoogleApiClient keeping the session?

Full source:

https://github.com/ivan-aguirre/chromecast_samples/blob/master/DropboxCast/app/src/main/java/com/dropboxcast/dropboxcast/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, I believe the proper way (or at least a better way) to approach this is one of the following:

- if you have only one activity and that is all you care about, then use a fragment that persists across configuration changes and put the stuff that you want to persist seamlessly, there. This way, rotation of the phone is not going to cause any disruption in your cast related stuff.
- if you have more than a single activity, think about creating an object that lasts across all your activities and put the cast stuff there and then ask that object for the instance of CastApi whenever needed, etc.

In your case, do you really get disconnected when you rotate the phone? Since you are setting up a whole new connection, you might want to disconnect yourself first when configuration changes (assuming you don't want to go with my earlier proposed (1) or (2)).

Comment: No, I don't disconnect. Reading your answer I now see I've misunderstood the "session restauration" stuff. If Activity is destroyed it makes sense to disconnect since it's supposed to be a user's desire to stop casting once casting is tied to Activity life cycle. The docs addresses the need for reconnection when process is killed.

Thanks Ali!!

Comment: Regarding the second way I believe I can do the same using a foreground service, leting user know application is connected and casting even if Activity is destroyed. It looks like Netflix app works like this.